# How to obtain all 1 digit or adjoining 2 digit combinations of a string

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, stl

Let's say I've a string `"12345"` I should obtain all **1 digit or adjoining 2 digit combinations** of this string such as:

```
1 2 3 4 5
12 3 4 5
1 23 45 
12 3 45 
12 34 5 
...
```

Please note that I grouped them in different number of chars but not changed their order. I need a method/function does that.

Any ideas on how to implement this.

Comment: Shouldn't be too hard - what have you tried so far ?

Comment: A pretty standard recursive algorithm should work here.

Comment: Using regices seems like overkill - there are much simpler ways.

Comment: As @Phylogenesis says, think about a recursive approach - take the first one or two characters from the string, and then process the remainder recursively for each of these two cases.

Comment: Well, why not simply run a loop and extract two nearby digits, then extract all single digits separably?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in a recursive way. Let's define `Ln` as the function to count all the ways we can patch the characters together this way. Imagine you are at the last character. You have two options, either use this character alone so we are left with `Ln-1` ways to do the rest or use this character and the one before it so we are left with `Ln-2` characters. Using this approach we can come up with a code like the one bellow:

```
void go(int i, const string &s, string res){
    if (i == s.length()) {
        cout << res << endl;
        return;
    }

    go(i + 1, s, res + s[i] + " ");
    if (i + 1 < s.length())
        go(i + 2, s, res + s[i] + s[i + 1] + " ");
}

int main()
{
    string s = "1234";
    go(0, s, "");
    return 0;
}
```